# How to do spring bean validations on particular fields for each request

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-bean

Exapmele : I have payment object with 3 request formats

1. request 1 card payment:
   validate card number, exp date and amount
2. token payment:
   token , exp date
3. validate card :
   card number, exp date

==> How it is possible from single payment object

Answer (score 0):

You should use ValidationGroups, and annotate the object you want apply specific validation to.

First create the validation groups (3 in your case):

```
public interface CardPayment {
}

public interface ValidateCard {
}

public interface TokenPayment {
}
```

apply the wanted validation checks on the Payment class (I've only included the @NotNull):

```
@Getter @Setter
public class Payment{
    @NotNull(groups = {CardPayment.class, ValidateCard.class })
    String card_num;

    @NotNull(groups = {CardPayment.class, TokenPayment.class, ValidateCard.class})
    Date expire_date;

    @NotNull(groups = {TokenPayment.class})
    String token;

    @NotNull(groups = {CardPayment.class})
    int amount;
}
```

And finally activate the validation on your controller (card payment scenario for example):

```
@RestController
public class PaymentController{
    @PostMapping("/payment")
    public ResponseEntity<?> cardPayment(@Validated({CardPayment.class}) @RequestBody Payment payment){
        // logic
    }

}
```